# Trace wcf service

Tags: c#, wcf, logging, trace, system.diagnostics

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
        <source name="System.ServiceModel"
                switchValue="Error, ActivityTracing"
                propagateActivity="true">
            <listeners>
                <add name="traceListener"
                     type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
                     initializeData= "c:\logs\Traces.svclog" />
            </listeners>
        </source>
    </sources>
</system.diagnostics>
```

Hi, I use this config section to trace just the errors from the WCF service, but when I open my svclog file I can see all the activity on the service. How can I log only the errors in my svclog file.

Comment: This link has exactly what you want:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4222023/wcf-tracing-of-only-failed-requests

Answer (score 1):

Remove "ActivtiyTracing" from the switchValue Attribute

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel"
              switchValue="Error"
              propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add name="traceListener"
              type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
              initializeData= "c:\logs\Traces.svclog" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
  </system.diagnostics>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can control Tracing by settings the Switch attribute :

```
 <configuration>
 <system.diagnostics>
    <switches>
       <add name="mySwitch" value="4" />
    </switches>
 </system.diagnostics>
```

The corresponding values are this :

```
    Trace Level

Off : 0
Error : 1
Warning : 2
Info : 3
Verbose : 4
```

On MSDN you will find more explanation

[TraceLevel Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracelevel.aspx)